# Dropdownlist is not binding selected value

Tags: development, sharepoint-server

Dropdownlist it binding only First value.If i selected second value also its binding first value
For example my deopdownlist List1,List2,List3 3 values are there ,I selected List3 but it bind List1

here is my code someone help me for this.

```
private void BindObligationType()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable aDtblOblType = objObligation.GetObligationsType();

            if (aDtblOblType != null)
            {
                DataRow dataRow = aDtblOblType.NewRow();
                dataRow["Title"] = Convert.ToString(objutility.GetResourceString("Obligation_Type_Validation"));
                dataRow["ContentTypeName"] = "None";
                aDtblOblType.Rows.InsertAt(dataRow, 0);

                ddlObligationType.DataSource = aDtblOblType;
               //ddlObligationType.DataValueField = "ContentTypeName";
                ddlObligationType.DataValueField = "Title";
                ddlObligationType.DataTextField = "Title";
                ddlObligationType.DataBind();
            }
}
```

}

Comment: you have some part missing in code.the code is not properly copy pasted.

Comment: Make sure you first call `BindObligationType()` before setting the value to dropdown

Comment: HI i edited my code now it was working.I gave the same value of "title" ddlObligationType.DataValueField and ddlObligationType.DataTextField
This is correct or wrong.

Comment: After i changed ddlObligationType.DataValueField = "Title"; now  Dropdown functionality is working but what i did is correct way or wrong please someone suggest me

Comment: **DataTextField** is what the user can see.
**DataValueField** is what you can use for identify which one is selected from DropDownList.

Like:

`<asp:ListItem id="opt_Audit" value="1" selected="False">One</asp:ListItem>`

Here 
**DataTextField** = One
**DataValueField** = 1

Comment: DataTextField  And DataValueField  i gave same value "Title" then only it was working.So where we can use dropdown we should give same value for DataTextField  and DataValueField   ?